# Listing php functions that were run to load page

Tags: php

I'm working on a custom website and currently integrating a new section. Having done everything exactly the same as with previous sections, the behavior achieved is different.

It would be useful if I could get a list of functions run once the page loads, just like when you get them listed if there is a critical error, without having any errors.

Can't find any information on this, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Xdebug execution trace: https://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All information that you need are in [xhprof](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php).

With that, you can check any function called in given request.